# Flot Chart not showing legend with options

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, charts, flot

[image]I cannot get the legend to show for anything in this flot chart.... I am using options to set all the options for the placeholder. Does anyone know how to get this to show up? The normal label and tooltip don't work either so if anyone knows how to get those to work or what I am doing wrong, that would be amazing. I have been pounding my head for three days now trying to figure out what is wrong.

The jquery is version 1.10.2 for jquery and the min file and 1.10.4 for the ui.

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.js?v1.8"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.mce.js?v1.8"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.time.js?v1.8"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.selection.js?v1.8"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.categories.js?v1.8"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>

    <h1>Flot Examples</h1>
<div id="placeholder" class="placeholder" style="width:500px; height:300px; background-color:darkcyan;"  runat="server"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data, data1, dataTime, options, chart;
    var date = new Date(); //2015
    var date1 = date.setDate(date.getDate());
    var date2 = date.setDate(date.getDate()-365); //2015
    var date3 = new Date(date.getFullYear() - 2, date.getMonth() - 5, date.getDate() - 6);

     data2 = [[date1, 1], [date2, 3], [date3, 6]];
   // data2 = [ dataTime];

    data1 = [ [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 9], [5, 7], [6, 6], [7, 2], [8, 1], [9, 3]];
    //data = [data1];

    var dataset= [
        {
            label: "data w Times",
            data: data2,
          //  color: "#ffffff"
        } /*,
        {
            label: "data1",
            data: data1
        }*/
    ];

    options = {
        series: 
        {
            //bars: { show: true }
            lines: {
                show: true,
               // fill: true,
                //fillColor: "#000000"
            },

        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            axisLabel: "foo"
        },
        yaxis: { 
            min: 1,
            axisLabel: "bar"
        },
        selection: { mode: "x" },
        grid: { show: true },
     //   clickable: true,
       // hoverable: true,
        shadowSize: 20,
        highlightColor: "#ffffff",  //this is the color of the circle that appears
        label: { string: "invisible" },
        tooltip: true,
        legend: {
            show: true,
            labelBoxBorderColor: "#ffffff",
            position: "ne",
            margin: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#66ccff",

        }

    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart1 = $.plot($(".placeholder"), data2, options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is anything showing? Is the chart there, but not the legend?

Comment: the chart is there. the legend is not, but I got the labels to show by using this:  var dataset= [
            {
                label: "data w Times",
                data: data2,
              //  color: "#ffffff"
            }

Comment: The "data w Times" is the legend. Right? Can you update your code to match what you're doing?

Comment: I updated the code as requested. In the flot options explanations, there is a legend and there is a label. Here the label acts as a legend, but I was wondering what the legend did or if it was different since I got this label to work.

Comment: I'm guessing one of your plugins is doing that. It's interpreting the label as the title for the legend, but not sure which one or where to make a change. Seems like this will work for you though.

Comment: Could you provice your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or code snippet?